# Можно ли сделать появление всплывающего окна на сайте через минуту после отсутствия активности?

Tags: javascript

Как можно сделать появление всплывающего окна на сайте, если человек не проявляет никакой активности на странице, не водит курсором? Например, через минуту после последнего движения миши или нажатия на клавиатуре. И после того, как окно появилось, пользователь его закрывает и оно больше само не выскакивает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря, подобные окна люто-бешено раздражают. А вдруг я читаю или отвлекся на что-то? А тут Бац! - и окно какое-то.

Но все же, есть вот такое [решение](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-For-Mouse-Stop-Event-mousestop.html).

А чтобы больше не вылазило, пишите в куки.